# Subject alternative name in iKeyman v7.0

Tags: ssl-certificate, websphere

Subject alternative name missing in iKeyman utility v7.0. Can it be enabled?

Have tried creating the .arm file through the iKeyman utility but certificate signing shows error as SAN is missing.

Comment: Ikeyman V7 is the Ikeyman bundled with java 5?  That's a long-since obsolete codebase to be generating certificates from.

Comment: Yes. Bundled with SDK5